# IOptionsSnapshot not refreshes after *.json file changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I followed the hello world example form [IOptionsSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#ioptionssnapshot), but the content is not refreshed after file `config.json` is changed and saved.

My dev environment:

1.VS 2017

2 .csproj file below

```
  <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
        <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
        <AssemblyName>UsingOptions</AssemblyName>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <PackageId>UsingOptions</PackageId>
        <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
        <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
      </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Below is the code from [IOptionsSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#ioptionssnapshot)

```
config.json:
{
  "Time": {
    "Message": "Hello "
  }
}


public class TimeOptions
{
    // Records the time when the options are created.
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    // Bound to config. Changes to the value of "Message"
    // in config.json will be reflected in this property.
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Controller
{
    public readonly TimeOptions _options;

    public Controller(IOptionsSnapshot<TimeOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    public Task DisplayTimeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(_options.Message + _options.CreationTime);
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            // reloadOnChange: true is required for config changes to be detected.
            .AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Simple mockup of a simple per request controller that writes
        // the creation time and message of TimeOptions.
        app.Run(DisplayTimeAsync);
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Simple mockup of a simple per request controller.
        services.AddScoped<Controller>();

        // Binds config.json to the options and setups the change tracking.
        services.Configure<TimeOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Time"));
    }

    public Task DisplayTimeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        return context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<Controller>().DisplayTimeAsync(context);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you changing the correct file? If the base path is current directory, and you've got it copying the config, should you be changing the one in the build folder? Just a thought!

Comment: Only one config.json file, which is within VS. I checked that.

Answer (score 0):

The source code of IOptions and IOptionsSnapshot look the same. Those interfaces have common implementation in [OptionsManager](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/OptionsManager.cs). So OptionsSnapshot does not reload options. Instead of IOptionsSnapshot, use IOptionsMonitor. You do not need to subscribe to OnChange event, just access to CurrentValue property.

**UPD**
Since Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.x release IOptionsSnapshot has been removed.